# Multiple databases on the same freeradius

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, freeradius

I am wondering if there are any way to use two different databases within the same freeradius instance?

ubuntu 22.04

freeradius 3.0

mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

describe your scenario in details

```
$ cd /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled
$ cp ../mods-available/sql ../mods-available/sql1
$ cp ../mods-available/sql ../mods-available/sql2
$ ln -s ../mods-available/sql1 sql1
$ ln -s ../mods-available/sql2 sql2

$ nano ../mods-available/sql1
sql sql1 {
        group_attribute = "${.:instance}-SQL-Group"
#       group_attribute = "SQL-Group"
}

$ nano ../mods-available/sql2
sql sql2 {
        group_attribute = "${.:instance}-SQL-Group"
#       group_attribute = "SQL-Group"
}

$ nano ../sites-available/default
authorize {
#       -sql
        redundant-load-balance sql {
                sql1
                sql2
        }
}
```

Comment: I have an accounting server.

sq1 is running successfully.

sq2 does not fetch the login user's; radacct-radpostauth; information

Would you help me with this topic?

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple modules of `sql` do this:

```
sql sql_first_database {
  driver = "..."
  .... #rest of the db config
}

sql sql_second_database {
  driver = "..."
  .... #rest of the db config
}
```

In your virtual servers:

```
server V1 {
 # other configs
  sql_first_database  # replace sql
  }

server V1 {
  # other configs
  sql_second_database   # replace sql
  }
```