# Freeradius 3.0 with two mysql

Tags: mysql, database, wifi, freeradius, radius

i have two database servers with one ip each. Does anyone know how I can do in freeradius 3.0 to pull a main database server, and if it goes down, to pull another one? I've managed to pull both, but if one doesn't work, the freeradius service does not start Thank you very much in advance. I have followed this post [Multiple databases on the same freeradius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298008/multiple-databases-on-the-same-freeradius) but nothing

I have tried the previous link that I mention and nothing, I don't know what to do, I have tried in many ways.

Comment: Hello, Im looking for a similar answer, did you figure it out?